# Google Play Store developer console: Unable to manage testers list for closed beta testing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Google upgraded the Play Store developer console on 18th April 2017 and as a part of this upgrade, the APK page (which was used to create new app releases for alpha, beta and production tracks) was replaced with an App Releases page.

Managing closed beta testing on the APK page was a pretty straightforward process, you simply choose the beta tab and select from the list of testers previously added.

Since the upgrade to App Releases, I'm unable to manage the testers lists from the page.

As per Google's help page on this topic - 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213, I should get an option to manage the testers list under the "Choose testing method" option. However, as can be seen in the screenshot below, that option is not there:

[image: Google Play Console App Releases page]

I've also tried emailing Google in this regard, but haven't heard back since. :(

Any help or pointers in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem too. It's just an issue with their CSS. Click the blank space next to "Closed Beta Testing" on the right, it will expand the section.

Comment: I chatted with Google Developer Support, and yes, amazingly this is the correct answer.

Comment: Unbelievable. This is a company with billions and billions of turnover, and they can't get this right?

Comment: @andrewprocter you saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Google Developer support by email regarding this issue and they instructed me to use Google Chrome to access the Play Console (I was using Safari).

On Google Chrome, you can see the down arrow next to the "Closed Beta Testing" option, which is not visible in Safari (due to a CSS issue as given in @andrewprocter's answer above). However, clicking on the empty space to the right of "Closed Beta testing" (where the arrow should actually appear) opens the menu containing the testers list.